# DependencyProperty ignores OnPropertyChanged();

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, binding

I have `PointsListView` and `PointContainer: INotifyPropertyChanged, ICollection<Point>`.

```
public class PointContainer: INotifyPropertyChanged, ICollection<Point>
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Point> Points
        {
            get
            {
                return points.Values;
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            points.Clear();
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Points"));
        }

...

}
```

For the reliability I made a binding from code:

```
private void BindPointContainerToListView()
{
   Binding binding = new Binding();
   binding.Source = PointContainer;
   binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Points");
   PointsListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
}
```

Why when change PointContainer is not automatically updated PointsListView.ItemsSource.
PointsListView.Items.Refresh (); solves the problem, but why does not work automatically? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to update when you add or remove a point, you need to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  (`ObservableCollection<T>` provides a collection implementation that does this for you...)

If you want it to update when a point's value is changed, then your `Point` class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Above I wrote that PointContainer implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @KovpaevAlexey Re-read what I posted - it needs to implement INotify **Collection** Changed.